# Whole system freezes when using Blender 2.93 LTS on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: modeling

I tried with blender 2.93 LTS and 3.0 Alpha on Ubuntu 20.04. But it randomly freezes the whole system. Sometimes blinking. I can't access other windows or the shell. I can open the terminal by hitting F3 +ctrl +alt. It doesn't work even when I try to kill blender. Only thing I can do is to reboot my system using "systemctl reboot -i" command.

I'm not doing any heavy work, just nearly 1000-5000 polygon low poly work.

My system is Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4 , AMD® Radeon (tm) r5 m315 / Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2), 0.5 SSD (UBUNTU 20.04 installed) & 1.0 HDD, 8 GB RAM

Comment: It's in 'alpha' state so do not expect miracles. However, I'd suggest file a bug report (In Blender > Help > Report a Bug) which might help getting it into beta state :) If Blender 2.92 is working on your system, there is no reason why 3.0 shouldn't.

Comment: @brockmann No my Blender version is 2.93 LTS (which crashed) I also tried the alpha version 3.0, got the same issue

Comment: That's odd. Most likely your graphics card... not sure, sorry.

Comment: My blender program worked perfectly few months ago. I don't know what has happened now

Comment: Graphics card driver update?

Comment: I did everything I could do. Now I have no idea - I stopped using blender because I can't format my computer right now. I'm going to format and reinstall Ubuntu